# sed + remove string only in the last line of the file

Tags: sed

I use the following sed command to remove the `line number` string from file

```
sed -i s'/line number//g' file
```

but what I need to change in  `sed` syntax in order to remove the `line number`
only if it exist in the last line of the file?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, however this can help you :

```
sed -i '$ s/line number//g' file
```

This will perform substitution only on last line (because of `$`), replacing `line number` by nothing.

`man sed`, section **Addresses** can help you understand how to apply sed commands on part of the text.

Comment: Why does 'space' come after '$'?

Comment: Yes as @firo has asked, why did you put a space? And why didnn't you put a semicolon instead?

Answer (score 4):

For those who are on SunOS which is non-GNU, the following code will help:

```
sed '$d' tmp.dat > test.dat
```

Comment: For those curious, `/bin/sed` on OmniOS/illumos has sed replaced with the BSD version (in addition to GNU sed), where Scharron's answer works.

Comment: you may be looking for `sed '${/pattern/d}'`