# string modification in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to generate SQL table header from a csv file. As I had some trouble I wrote a test snippet, here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
function quote {
   for i ; do
#       echo "\`$i\`"
        echo "\`$i\` varchar (100),\n"
   done
}

quote $(head -1 Zustaendigkeit.csv | sed 's/;/ /g')
```

This is the csv line I use:

Netz;Strasse;PLZ_Ort;Land;Amt;Amt_Nr;PLZ;Ort

This is what I get with the above snippet:

```
[root@db ~]
 174# ./tst.sh
`Netz` varchar (100),\n
`Strasse` varchar (100),\n
`PLZ_Ort` varchar (100),\n
`Land` varchar (100),\n
`Amt` varchar (100),\n
`Amt_Nr` varchar (100),\n
`PLZ` varchar (100),\n
` varchar (100),\n
```

In the last line it's missing `Ort at the beginning of the line. When I use only "echo "\`$i`"" which is commented in the above snippet I get this:

```
[root@db ~]
 170# ./tst.sh
`Netz`
`Strasse`
`PLZ_Ort`
`Land`
`Amt`
`Amt_Nr`
`PLZ`
`Ort
```

Which is missing the last `

Hope someone has the missing link for me....

Greetz
Mirco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `awk`? I used to do this:

```
 awk -v Q="'" -F "," 'NR==1 { print "create table SOMETABLE ("
                              for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
                                  print $i " varchar2(100), "
                              }
                              print $NF " varchar2(100) );"
                      }
                      NR%1000 == 0 { print "commit;" }
                      { print "insert into SOMETABLE values ( "
                        for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
                             print Q $i Q ", "
                        }
                        print Q $NF Q " );"
                      }
                      END { print "commit;"
                            print "exit;"
                      }' INPUT.CSV > SQL.sql
```

Comment: To load the data I use:                                            LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/Zustaendigkeit.csv' INTO TABLE Zustaendigkeit
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';

Comment: Well then you can use only the `NR==1` part of the `awk` script to generate the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a Windows line end at the end of the line. Remove it: `sed 's/\r//g'`.

Instead of using `sed`, you can use a loop and set IFS to `;`. Removing of the `\r` is done by parameter expansion.

```
IFS=';'
read -a a < Zustaendigkeit.csv
for b in "${a[@]}" ; do
    echo "\`${b%$'\r'}\` varchar(100)"
done
```

Comment: Thx that was my Prob which is now solved... Added a comma after varchar but I need the last echo'd line to be without a comma: any hint is very appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576139/sed-remove-string-only-in-the-last-line-of-the-file did the trick...