# Replace a particular string (at fixed position) in a text file by line number

Tags: bash, text, sed, replace

I built a script (bash) to replace a figure in a specific position on a .txt file.

This is the file, data.txt:

```
Date; Buy; Sell; Coupon; Fee
21/6/2019;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;0.0000000000
```

I want to replace the 12th character.

Find below the part of the code that changes the position if the 12th position is equal to "0" change the figure to "59"

```
sed 's/^\(.\{11\}\)0/\159/' data.txt
```

All good so far, the problem is when I want to make the changes only on the last row (#34)image a file (data.txt) as:

```
Date; Buy; Sell; Coupon; Fee
26/4/2006;0.0000000000;-200000000.0;0.0000000000
4/5/2006;0.0000000000;-100000000.0;0.0000000000
4/5/2006;0.0000000000;-300000000.0;0.0000000000
1/12/2006;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-30000000.00
5/12/2006;0.0000000000;-250000000.0;0.0000000000
8/12/2006;0.0000000000;-250000000.0;0.0000000000
19/12/2006;0.0000000000;-650000000.0;0.000000000
18/1/2007;0.0000000000;-250000000.0;0.0000000000
1/2/2007;0.0000000000;-250000000.0;0.0000000000
2/2/2007;0.0000000000;-720000000.0;0.0000000000
28/3/2007;0.0000000000;-200000000.0;0.0000000000
28/3/2007;0.0000000000;-400000000.0;0.0000000000
3/5/2007;0.0000000000;-250000000.0;0.0000000000
3/5/2007;0.0000000000;-750000000.0;0.0000000000
3/5/2007;0.0000000000;-250000000.0;0.0000000000
5/6/2007;0.0000000000;-500000000.0;0.0000000000
3/7/2007;0.0000000000;-300000000.0;0.0000000000
3/12/2007;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-281000000.0
1/12/2008;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-281000000.0
1/12/2009;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-281000000.0
1/12/2010;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-281000000.0
5/4/2011;525000000.00;0.0000000000;0.0000000000
1/12/2011;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-254750000.0
2/11/2012;1348000000.0;0.0000000000;0.0000000000
2/11/2012;840000000.00;0.0000000000;0.0000000000
3/12/2012;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-145350000.0
2/12/2013;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-145350000.0
1/12/2014;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-145350000.0
1/12/2015;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-145350000.0
1/12/2016;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-145350000.0
1/12/2017;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-145350000.0
3/12/2018;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;-145350000.0
21/6/2019;0.0000000000;0.0000000000;0.0000000000
```

I used the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while read line;do
if((i==34));then
sed 's/^\(.\{11\}\)0/\159/' data.txt
fi
((i++))
```

Seems that there is a problem with the condition, the script runs a never stop, no output produced is like a loop without end.

Comment: Please wrap your samples/codes in CODE TAGS as per forum rules, edit your post and let us know then.

Comment: Subbing the twelfth character will produce inconsistent results because your first field (date) is variable-length. Please edit your question to include your exact desired output.

Comment: Hello community, I edited my post now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LorenzoCastagno Please edit your question to include exact desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed + remove string only in the last line of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576139/sed-remove-string-only-in-the-last-line-of-the-file)

Comment: Hi @vintnes My desired output: 21/6/2019;59;0.0000000000;0.0000000000

Comment: That does not just `replace the 12th character` as you said you wanted. It replaces a whole `0.000...` number with `59` and deletes all lines up until that last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '$s/^\([^;]\+;\)0\(.*\)/\159\2/' input
```

The address `$` tells `sed` to work only on the last line in the file. Instead of replacing the 12th character it is probably wise to replace the character after the  first `;`.

It makes absolutely no sense to split the lines for `sed` with a `bash`. It is one of `sed`'s core features to loop over lines.

Comment: Capturing the end of the line (after the 0) is useless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Why? He says: "I want to replace the 12th character."

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `\+` but if you have to use GNU sed then you could use EREs like `sed -E '$s/^([^;]+;)0(.*)/\159\2/'` to avoid so much escaping and then that'd work in OSX/BSD sed too. If you wanted a POSIX version it'd be `sed '$s/^\([^;]\{1,\};\)0\(.*\)/\159\2/'`. @CasimiretHippolyte is right though, you don't need the 2nd capture group, all you need is `sed -E '$s/^([^;]+;)0/\159/'`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why is useless? I want to replace the 12th character in the last row!

Comment: @LorenzoCastagno run `echo 'abc' | sed 's/b/X/'` and it'll output `aXc`. Now run `echo 'abc' | sed 's/b\(.*\)/X\1/'` and it'll also output `aXc`. Now ask yourself - what benefit did writing `\(.*\)` and `\1` in the 2nd script to capture what's left on the line after the part you're interested in give you? The answer is none, just like with the script in this answer.

Comment: Indeed `sed '$s/^\([^;]*;\)0/\159/'` does exactly the same thing (without to have to describe the end of the line).

Answer (score 1):

The following works with `gawk`, `mawk`, `original-awk`, and `busybox`:

```
awk 'END {if(int($2)==0) $2=59; print}' {O,}FS=\; data.txt
```

Outputs:

```
21/6/2019;59;0.0000000000;0.0000000000
```

On the last record (line), awk checks the integer value of the second semicolon `;` delimited field, changing it to 59 if it's equal to zero.

Comment: That's relying on undefined behavior since the value of `$0` in the `END` section is undefined by POSIX. In some awks it'll be the value of the last $0 read, in others it'll be null and in others it could be/do anything else. It'll do what you want in GNU awk, idk which others.

Comment: @EdMorton I tested against `mawk`, `gawk`, and `original-awk`. It feels preposterous to discard a working solution on the basis of a weak standard. I would very much like to know if you find a version that doesn't do this.

Comment: HP-UX awk is one (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29970249/1745001). See also the discussion on this at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND - `all of BWK awk, mawk, and gawk preserve the value of $0 for use in END rules. Be aware, however, that some other implementations and many older versions of Unix awk do not.`. I'm not suggesting you discard the solution, just mention that it'll only behave as expected with an awk that supports $0, etc. as desired in the END section.

Comment: @EdMorton valuable information; will keep this in mind for the older NACs I have to deal with.

Comment: idk what a `NAC` is but dont assume this is only a problem with older UNIX installations or awk versions, as the awk manual says "**some other implementations** and many older versions of Unix awk do not." - it's not just "many older vesions". Just remember to say "works if..." if/when you're counting on this and then it's all good.